# What the best way to pass ngClass to child component without touch the main component

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular-library

I'm looking for the best way to pass `ngClass` or `ngStyle` to a subcomponent but without apply to the main component.

For example:

I have a component "button" that I call in app.component.html

```html
<app-button [ngClass]="{'d-none': true}"></app-button>
```

My component reflects a native button.

```js
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
@Input('ngClass') ngClass: NgClass["ngClass"]
}
```

```html
<button [ngClass]="ngClass"></button>
```

My issue in this case is that `d-none` will apply on the virtual element `<app-button></app-button>` and not only on the real `button` element. Because my CSS class `d-none` is global. Which can cause issue if I want apply this CSS on a specific element of the component.

The only solution I see is to rename `ngClass` @Input property of the component. But there is maybe a better way to do? A way to not apply `ngClass` directly on the component maybe?

Comment: It sounds like you want to add an @Input like `buttonClass`, and then bind that to the button's class attribute inside your app-button component?

Comment: You need to rename the input to something else, naming it `ngClass` won't work. Then just make and bind a function to ngClass of the button returning that input or an empty string.